# why do we need np.squeeze()?

Tags: python, numpy

Very often, arrays are squeezed with `np.squeeze()`. In the documentation, it says

> Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of a.

However I'm still wondering: Why *are* zero and nondimensional entries in the shape of a? Or to put it differently: Why do both `a.shape = (2,1)` *and* `(2,)` exist?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Besides the mathematical differences between the two things, there is the issue of predictability. If your suggestion was followed, you could at no point rely on the dimension of your array. So any expression of the form `my_array[x,y]` would need to be replaced by something that first checks if `my_array` is actually two-dimensional and did not have an implicit `squeeze` at some point. This would probably obfuscate code far more than the occasional `squeeze`, which does a clearly specified thing.

Actually, it might even be very hard to tell, which axis has been removed, leading to a whole host of new problems.

In the spirit of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), also `Explicit is better than implicit`, we can also say that we should prefer explicit `squeeze` to implicit array conversion.

Comment: Great answer. It's also worth pointing out that MATLAB/Octave do not have implicit squeeze either. If numpy had an implicit squeeze, that would be one more obstacle for people making the switch to Python/numpy.

Answer (score 28):

This helps you get rid of useless one dimension arrays like using 
`[7,8,9]` instead of `[[[7,8,9]]]`
or `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` instead of `[[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]]`.
Check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_squeeze.htm) from tutorials point for example.

Answer (score 8):

One example of the importance is when multiplying arrays. Two 2-dimensional arrays will multiply each value at a time

e.g.

```
>>> x = np.ones((2, 1))*2
>>> y = np.ones((2, 1))*3
>>> x.shape
(2,1)
>>> x*y
array([[ 6.],
       [ 6.]])
```

If you multiply a 1d array by a 2d array then the behaviour is different

```
>>> z = np.ones((2,))*3
>>> x*z
array([[ 6.,  6.],
       [ 6.,  6.]])
```

Secondly, you also might want to squeeze the earlier dimensions e.g. a.shape = (1,2,2) to a.shape = (2,2)

Comment: Fixed to a more conventional style

Answer (score 8):

When you squeeze a (2,1) array, you get (2,) which works as both (2,1) and (1,2):

```
>>> a = np.ones(2)
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a.T.shape
(2,)
>>> X = np.ones((2,2))*2
>>> np.dot(a,X)
[4. 4.]
>>> np.dot(X,a)
[4. 4.]
```

This cannot happen with a (2,1) array:

```
>>> b = np.ones((2,1))
>>> np.dot(b,X)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```