# Reduce tuple of one item (singleton) to its value

Tags: python

Is there a built-in way to reduce a [singleton tuple](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/tuple/#tuple) to its (only) value?

I can achieve this using a function like:

```
def foo(tup):
    if len(tup) == 1:
        return tup[0]
    return tup
```

This reduces a singleton to its value and leaves a non-singleton tuple as is:

```
>>> x = (3, )
>>> foo(x)
3
>>> x = (3, 4)
>>> foo(x)
(3, 4)
```

But this seems like a fairly low-level task and I bet it's already lurking somewhere in the Python standard library. The functionality kind of reminds me of [`numpy.squeeze`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990652/why-do-we-need-np-squeeze) but that leaves us with an `array` which may not be what we want.

Comment: There's not a builtin way... what'd happen for instance with an empty tuple, does that remain an empty tuple or a fallback value such as `None` ? (not to mention if you're expecting tuples that sometimes may not be - umm...)

Comment: On the other hand, the task may be too short and simple to have a library function for it.

Comment: Would doing this not need you to use special logic when using the value here to figure out if you have a tuple or a value? What are you using this for?

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? Seems like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). What are you [really trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: What they said. Functions that return different types at different times are generally a pain to work with. Calling `len` on a tuple is very cheap, and simpler than having to calling `isinstance` to determine what type the function actually returned. And of course we generally try to avoid calling `isinstance` since that interferes with duck-typing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built-in way to extract the single item out of a one-tuple. That way is accessing its first index, i.e. `tpl[0]`.

But no, there is no built-in way to extract a one-tuple into its single value but leave all other tuples as they are. And if you think about it, this would be a kind of dangerous operation to do:

The fact that you need to check its length means that you probably don’t know whether it’s a one-tuple or a tuple of a different size. And this means that you also cannot tell what the return value of your function is: It could be either a tuple (of any size other than 1), or it could be something else (i.e. the value of the one-tuple). That makes your function very fragile since it no longer has a clear return type.

While something like `len(x)` would work fine for a tuple `x`, `len(foo(x))` would likely not in case `x` was a one-tuple and the element inside is not a sequence. Or `list(x)` would convert the tuple into a list; but `list(foo(x))` would convert it into a list, or convert whatever was inside into a list.

So your function does not really make much of a sense if you think about it. And that’s probably the reason why there is no “unpack single value if there is one” function.

That being said, you can unpack the first value of a tuple of any length (larger than 0). Maybe that is what you actually want to do:

```
>>> x = 1,
>>> y = 2, 3
>>> z = 4, 5, 6
>>> a, *_ = x
>>> a
1
>>> b, *_ = y
>>> b
2
>>> c, *_ = z
>>> c
4
```

Answer (score 2):

It could pass as a low level task, but it's not something you do every now and then; no reason to dedicate a builtin for this. No direct function to do this, you can however do it *flat* using a ternary conditional:

```
x = tup[0] if len(tup) == 1 else tup
```

Comment: It is, however, debatable if this more readable and it's still only reusable if wrapped in a function.

Comment: @schwobaseggl There is nearly no line of code that doesn't qualify as debatable. Except it's written by GvR.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that the tuple has one element, you could just unwrap it

```
value, = x
```

But there is no built-in way that also checks